# Spring Boot 1.4 and Apache Axis2 - Tomcat doesn't start by running Jar

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, apache-axis

I am now using Spring Boot 1.4 and Apache Axis2 in my project. After adding dependencies in pom.xml, the generated jar file can't run. It means the tomcat server doesn't start and

```
java.util.concurrent.ExeutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solved the problem by adding exclusions in pom.xml. I think the problem is the embed Tomcat has some problems with javax.servlet-api.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```